# Can we make build of Angular project using Apache Ant build.xml?

Tags: angular, ant, devops, war

I am trying to build of the Angular project using Apache Ant via `build.xml`  but I could not find anything on internet, is it even possible to make build of Angular project using Apache Ant via `build.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However, the much more important question is

> Should you build an Angular project in Ant?

The answer to that question is:
No.